# Como verificar quais números de uma matriz são primos?

Tags: python

Meu código até agora

```
def numerosPrimos(matrix):
lista_primos = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for a in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][a] > 1:
            for c in range(2,matrix[i][a]):
                if matrix[i][a] % c != 0:
                    lista_primos.append(matrix[i][a])
print(f'Lista dos numeros primos da matriz: {lista_primos}')
```

Output:

```
Lista dos numeros primos da matriz: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 8, 8, 8, 8, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]
```

Comment: Faltou a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para tornar mais facil, vou exemplificar com listas puras do python e não matrizes, mas a solução pode ser facilmente adptada para matrizes.

Primeiro vamos criar uma função para checar se um numero é ou não primo:

> Editada
>   Depois da observação do Pedro Herique, alterei o codigo da função `is_prime`.
> Atualizado também no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/list-primes)

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number in [2, 3, 5, 7]:
        return True
    if number<2 or number%2==0 or number%3==0:  
        return False

    sqr = int(number**0.5)
    fact = 5
    while fact <= sqr:
        if number%fact==0 or number%(fact+2)==0: return False
        fact+=6

    return True
```

Agora vamos definar uma outra funcao para filtrar os primos de uma lista:

```
def lst_primes(lst):
    return list(set([number for number in lst if is_prime(number)]))
```

Finalmente vamos testar:

```
lst_numbers = [73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,17,19,23,25,66,73,101]
primes = lst_primes(lst_numbers)
print(primes)
```

Saida:

```
[97, 101, 103, 73, 107, 109, 79, 113, 17, 83, 19, 23, 89, 127]
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/list-primes)

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Sidon esta parcialmente correta, mas a função is_prime(n) é limitada ao intervalo 0 a 340, uma função is_prime_Corrected(n) foi feita no exemplo abaixo e demonstra como is_prime(n) pode errar.

**Importantíssimo: não há formula que possa prever se um número é primo a não ser por força bruta. Existem formulas que geram primos, mas nem todos os primos são gerados por elas! A ocorrência de um número primo é totalmente aleatória!**

```py
primos = []
primos2 =[]
until = 30000

def is_prime(n):
        return (2 in [n, 2**n%n] and n%3!=0) or n==3

def is_prime_Corrected(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
             return (False,i)
    return (n!=1),0


for n in range(1,until):
    if is_prime(n):
        primos.append(n)

for i in range(1,until):
    if is_prime_Corrected(i)[0]:
        if not is_prime(i):
            print("Embora",i,"seja um numero primo, is_prime o ignorou")
        primos2.append(i)
    elif i in primos:
            print(i,"pode ser dividido por",is_prime_Corrected(i)[1],'mas foi adicionado em "primos"')          

print(primos == primos2)
```

- Observações: a função is_prime pode ser usada para verificar se um número não é primo (usando not is_prime(n)) e acelerar o processamento pelo menos até 30.000, talvez mais

Comment: para testar pro seu computador se algum número primo não é inserido em is_prime use "until = 2**sys.maxsize" mas provavelmente o programa vai rodar por alguns anos

Comment: Veja minha sollucao funcionando [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/list-primes), tem varios numeros acima de 340, como por exemplo 5003.

Comment: A sua solução não funciona corretamente pois retorna números não primos como primos, exemplos 341, 1105 https://repl.it/repls/BarrenPreciousWordprocessing

Comment: Verdade, fiz testes e constatei o erro, mas refiz a função, testei e parece que agora esta ok.

Comment: Em tempo: Obrigado pelo alerta!

Comment: o link https://www.dcode.fr/primality-test prove uma solução muito boa pra isso (100x mais rápida do que a naive que eu coloquei aqui)

Comment: A solução que vc usou agora é a solução padrão otimizada

Comment: É, tenho uma coletania de algoritmos p checagem de numeros primos, a primeira que usei era parte de um exemplo dos primordios do Javascript, provavelmente eu devo ter perdido alguma parte do codigo qdo guardei. Mas é isso que dá não testar. :-) De qualquer forma essa ultima solução ficou bem rapida, mesmo com numeros grandes (claro que não muuuuito).

Comment: a sua solução é uma solução probabilística, há baixa probabilidade de que n seja não primo caso `(2 in [n, 2**n%n] and n%3!=0) or n==3`, mas há 100% de probabilidade de que isso é verdadeiro caso o número seja primo.

Comment: Não considero mais a primeira solução, morreu! :-)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91457/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-monforte-and-sidon).